# Parsing a string to find element

Tags: python, string, list

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def split(x):
    return [char for char in x]
def func(x):
    a = []
    a.append(split(x))
    for i in a:
        if a[i]== "\"":
            print ("hw")
str = "string\""
print (str)
func(str)
```

Trying to implement a function which finds `"` in a string and prints `"hw"` when finds it. What could be the problem?

Comment: would `'"' in x` not suffice?

Comment: In terms of your question, you're using `append` instead of `extend` to add a collection of elements to your list (amongst other things..)

Comment: `i` is a `string` not an integer (index)

Comment: @Sayse if a[i]== '"':
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list

Comment: @DanielMesejo Why? Used to code in c so it's very confusing

Comment: @dhvcc - python for loops are akin to c# foreach loops

Comment: When you do `for i in a` you are iterating over a "list" (for lack of a better name) of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **list indices must be integers, not list**.

I modify your code, so, try code below:

```py
def split(x):
    return [char for char in x]
def func(x):
    a = split(x)  # notice this line
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i]== "\"":
            print ("hw")
str1 = "string\""
print (str1)
func(str1)
```

[@See this Ouput Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iU3u5.png)

Or:

```py
def split(x):
    return [char for char in x]
def func(x):
    a = split(x)
    for i in a:
        if i == "\"":
            print ("hw")
str1 = "string\""
print (str1)
func(str1)
```

Or:

```py
str1 = "string\""
test = ["hw" for i in str1 if i == '"']
print(test[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE

Actually it is much simpler than you think. First of all `split` is a built-in function. Secondly the `for i in a` checks every character of string `a` you do not need an index. Try the following:

```
s = "string\""
print("hw" if "\"" in s else None)
```

if you need to also get the indexes of the found characters you can do this:

```
s = "string\"\""
print([(i, "hw") for i, j in enumerate(s) if j == "\""])
```

Comment: How can i get the index of an element?

Comment: @dhvcc updated the answer so you can get the indexes too.